# Why does VSS terminate unexpectedly?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vss

I have a Windows 2003 SP2 server, both physical and VM

When my backup agent tries to take backup VSS fails with below error message. Also this error message is intermittent(some days it comes and some days it doesn't come up)

```
Source:      Service Control Manager
Category:    None
Event ID:    7034
Description: The Volume Shadow Copy service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this n time(s).
```

I have also checked for the vssadmin list writers - It's all stable.

We are using EMC Avamar to backup this windows machine.

Comment: Are your disks OK?  Is there anything happening around the same time-frame as when you get these messages (ie: Previous Versions tasks)? When it does give you this error, does the backup work anyway?

Comment: @techie007 Yep, all the disks seems to be ok.The before and after messages are below: Before: **Event ID: 7036 The Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider service entered the stopped state.** After: **Event ID: 7035 The Volume Shadow Copy service was successfully sent a start control.** The backup skips the systemstate backup whenever this error encounters.

Comment: Sorry, I never thought abt that. I have done that :) sorry again